# Filtering Products of same price in one page wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So i have an online store with variations of products but ill like to have a page that shows products with a price range. Say I have a page called 3k Store. I want such that when a user goes to that page, it filters and displays only goods that cost 3000, Please how do i go about this? I am using wordpress and woocommerce. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Create a page template to list products

Create a page template to be able to put some code on it. Name it `page.list-product-in-range.php` for example and add this code at the start of the file to make it a template :

```
<?php // Template Name: List product in range ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

### 2. Create a page in the wordpress admin

Create a page named `Product that cost 3000`for example and select the template previously created. That's all for the moment.

### 3. Go to the php file that we created in part **`1`**

Between `<?php get_header(); ?>` and `<?php get_footer(); ?>`, add this part to get the products that cost 3000 :

( I let the range in the `meta_query` so you can easily set something else than 3000 by playing with the number inside `value`)

```
<?php 
    $products = get_posts(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => '_price',
                    'value'   => array(
                        3000 ,
                        3000
                    ),
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                    'type'=> 'NUMERIC'
                )
            )
        )
    );
?>
```

### 4. Add the loop to list products

After the code that we added in part **`3`** put this code :

```
<ul class="products">
    <?php

        if (!empty($products)) {
            foreach ( $products as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endforeach;
        } else {
            echo __( 'No products found', 'woocommerce' );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul>
```

You also can use `pre_get_posts` hook to set the products in the main query or instead of `get_posts()` use the `WP_Query` class. I only use `get_posts()` for the simplicity .

If you need pagination (and i think you will need), you should think about using pre_get_posts or WP_Query.

---

**Code tested and it works.**